# Find Cook's Distance on Predicted Values for LM

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, outliers

#### Problem

I would like to use Cook's distance to identify outliers in my predicted data.

#### Background

I know it is easy to find the outliers in the original data used to build a linear model using `cooks.distance()` (illustrated in **Example 1** below).

#### More Explanation of Problem

When I fit new data with that model (using `predict()`), I can't see how to get the Cook's distance on the new points since `cooks.distance()` only operates on a `model` object. I understand that it is calculated by a leave-one-out method iteratively rebuilding the model so perhaps it doesn't make sense to calculate it on fitted values but I was hoping that I'm missing something simple about how one might approach this.

#### Desired Output

In **Example 2** below I show the predicted values where I'd like to highlight outliers in by their Cook's D, but since I didn't know how to do it I just used their residual to illustrate something close to my desired output.

#### Example 1

```r
# subset data
a <- mtcars[1:16,]
# build model on one half
m <- lm(mpg ~ disp, a)
# find outliers
c <- cooks.distance(m)
# visualize outliers with cook's d
pal <- colorRampPalette(c("black", "red"))(102)
with(a, 
     plot(mpg ~ disp, 
          col = pal[1 + round(100 * scale(c, min(c), max(c)))], 
          pch = 19,
          main = "Color by Cook's D")); abline(m)
```

[image]

#### Example 2

```r
# predict on full data and add residuals
b <- mtcars
b$pred_mpg <- predict(m, mtcars)
b$resid <- b$mpg - b$pred_mpg

# visualize outliers in full data by residuals
with(b, 
     plot(mpg ~ disp, 
          pch = 19, 
          col = pal[1 + round(100 * scale(resid, min(resid), max(resid)))],
          main = "Color by Residual")); abline(m)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I think that this may be impossible, effectively you're asking how much a point that's not used for fitting the model influences the model fit.

Comment: Right - that's what I was worried about. Is there a way to use this metric on fitted data then or do I need to find a different way to quantify outliers?